# Question about the Conditioning Augmentation technique?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, papers, generative-adversarial-networks

In the paper [StackGAN: Text to Photo-realistic Image Synthesis with Stacked Generative Adversarial Networks](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017/papers/Zhang_StackGAN_Text_to_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf), the goal is to convert text descriptions into images. The text encoder encodes the description to produce the text embedding. This text embedding is then fed into the Conditional Augmentation block. The output from this block is combined with the noise vector, then used as the input to the generator, this is the explanation of the Conditioning Augmentation technique:

> The text description $t$ is first encoded by an encoder, yielding a
> text embedding $\varphi_t$. However, latent space for text embedding
> is usually high dimensional ($>100$ dimensions). With limited amount
> of data, it usually causes discontinuity in the latent data manifold,
> which is not desirable for learning the generator. To mitigate this
> problem, we introduce a Conditioning Augmentation technique to produce
> additional conditioning text variables $\hat{c}_0$.

> More specifically, the conditioning text variable $\hat{c}_0$ is
> sampled from an independent Gaussian distribution
> $\mathcal{N}(\mu_0(\varphi_t),\sum_0(\varphi_t))$, where the mean
> $\mu_0(\varphi_t)$ and diagonal covariance matrix $\sum_0(\varphi_t)$ are
> functions of the text embedding $\varphi_t$, both of them are jointly
> learned with the rest of the network.

> $\varphi_t$ is first fed into a fully connected layer to obtain
> $\mu_0$ and $\sigma_0$ ($\sigma_0$ are the values in the diagonal of
> $\sum_0$) for the Gaussian distribution
> $\mathcal{N}(\mu_0(\varphi_t),\sum_0(\varphi_t))$. The conditioning text
> variable $\hat{c}_0$ is computed by
> $\hat{c}_0 = \mu_0 + \sigma_0 \odot \epsilon$, where $\odot$ is the
> element-wise multiplication and $\epsilon$ is from
> $\mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$ ($I_n$ is the identity matrix with $n$ equal to
> the dimension of $\varphi_t$). $\hat{c}_0$ is then concatenated with a
> standard Gaussian noise vector as the input of the generator.
> The proposed Conditioning Augmentation yields more training pairs
> given a small number of image-text pairs, and thus encourages
> robustness to small perturbations along the conditioning manifold.

Can someone explain the meaning of the first paragraph ?

I have another question, in the second paragraph "*$\hat{c}_0$ is sampled from an independent Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_0(\varphi_t),\sum_0(\varphi_t))$*" and in the third paragraph "*$\hat{c}_0$ is computed by $\hat{c}_0 = \mu_0 + \sigma_0 \odot \epsilon$*" ? So $\hat{c}_0$ can be computed in 2 ways? Are these statements contradict each other ?

In the third paragraph, can someone explain what does this mean and how is this possible: "*The proposed Conditioning Augmentation yields more training pairs given a small number of image-text pairs, and thus encourages robustness to small perturbations along the conditioning manifold.*"

Thanks

Comment: I think this question should be asked on Stack Overflow or Cross Validated or Computer Science